# Python dataframe smaller value in first column but a higher value in second column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two columns. I want to get those rows. In which the value of first column is less but the value in second column is greater

```
id first- column second-column
0     2               1
1     1               9
2     3               5
3     7               2
4     0               1
5     9               3
6     1               5
7     7               2
```

i want result like this

```
id first-column  second-column
1    1             9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mask such:

```
mask = df.first_column < df.second_column
```

which values True in the cases where first_column is less than second_column.

Then you apply the mask to the dataframe (basically filtering only the mask rows that value to True):

```
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
   first_column second_column
1  1            3
2  3            5
4  0            1
6  1            5
```